# Facing error calling enum within header file

Tags: c

I've created the below function(**getHobby(Hobbies)**) within a header file and when I'm calling this function in the header file itself, I'm getting an error:

```
conflicting types for 'getHobby'
```

**HobbiesTest.h**

```
enum Hobbies {
    SKATING, SPORTS
}; 
char *getHobby(enum Hobbies hobbie) { <-- Compilation error "conflicing types for      
                                      'getHobby'
switch (hobbie) {
    case SKATING:
        return "SKATING";
    case SPORTS:
        return "SPORTS";
    }   
    return "INVALIDOPTION";
}
void enumTest(){
    printf("\nYour hobby is: %s",getHobby(SKATING));
}
```

And, when I'm calling the same function from the main file within some method, the same code is working fine.

Main.c

```
include <HobbiesTest.h>

int main(void) {    
    enumTest();
    return 0;
}

void enumTest(){
    printf("\nYour hobby is: %s",getHobby(SKATING));
}
```

Why I'm getting a compilation error in case of header file?

Comment: Also void enumTest() function is defined twice once in header and once in main.c

Comment: I've tested this code in two cases: 1. With Header file 2. From main file. When I created the function enumTest() in the Main.c file I removed it from the header file and when I created it into the header file, I just directly call it into the Main.c.

Comment: Ok, assuming that you have void enumTest() only in header file there is case SPORTS instead SPORTING... But thats probably all everything else seems to be Ok to me...

Comment: Yes it is SPORT and even the method getHobby(...) in the header file is compiling fine. But, when I'm writing the statement printf("\nYour hobby is: %s",getHobby(SKATING)); then I'm getting a compilation error. I'm not able to figure it out that why its not working in case of header file and the same method move to main it is give me right result.

Comment: I created a sample function                                     `char *getValue(){
 return "Value";
}`                                                                   and I execute the statement from a method(within header file) `char *ch = getValue();` that is also not working.

Comment: When I defined the prototype on the top of header file for `char *getValue();` it worked. Thanks @Sekory for your observation.

Comment: this kind of parameter: *getHobby(enum Hobbies hobbie) will usually result in the compiler stating that an incomplete enum is being defined.  so write it like this: *getHobby( int hobbie )

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
enum Hobbies {
    SKATING, SPORTING
};
```

At the start of header file. You using this enum before it is defined.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually, the enum Hobbies is already declared on the top of the header file. I apologize for writing it at the end here. I just copy paste the methods individually rather than pasting entire code. Sorry for that.

Comment: Well then edit your question we need to see exact code which is causing the trouble. My answer is maybe premature but this I just cannot overlooked it...